# Cannot start local kafka broker

Tags: java, apache-kafka

When I start a local kafka broker on my machine with the following config

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
```

It works fine. If, however I replace localhost with my machine name in advertised listeners as so

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092,SSL://localhost:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://GBV04303950:9092,SSL://GBV04303950:9093
```

Then it refuses to start up, with the error message

> [2019-03-12 17:32:00,179] WARN [Controller id=0, targetBrokerId=0]
>   Connection to node 0 (GBV04303950/10.202.32.140:9092) could not be
>   established. Bro ker may not be available.
>   (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient) [2019-03-12 17:32:00,203]
>   ERROR [KafkaApi-0] Number of alive brokers '0' does not meet the
>   required replication factor '1' for the offsets topic (conf igured via
>   'offsets.topic.replication.factor'). This error can be ignored if the
>   cluster is starting up and not all brokers are up yet. (kafka.server.
>   KafkaApis)

I have also tried it with the fully qualified hostname with domain name as returned by typing "ping localhost" at the prompt but the same error occurs.

Why is it unable to connect using the machine name but it can with localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that you need to configure both `SSL` and `PLAINTEXT` ports only if:

- SSL is not enabled for inter-broker communication
- Some clients connecting to the cluster do not use SSL

If this is the case, then the following example configuration should work:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://GBV04303950:9092,SSL://GBV04303950:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092,SSL://0.0.0.0:9093
```